# How does len function actually work for files?

Tags: python, function

The python docs say: Return the length (the number of items) of an object. The argument may be a sequence (string, tuple or list) or a mapping (dictionary).

**Code:**

```
from sys import argv

script, from_file = argv

input = open(from_file)
indata = input.read()

print "The input file is %d bytes long" % len(indata)
```

**Contents of the file:**
One two three

**Upon running this simple program I get as output:** The input file is 14 bytes long

**Qutestion:**

I don't understand, if my file has written in it only 11 characters(One two three) how can len return me 14 bytes and not just simply 11?(what's with the bytes by the way?) In the python interpreter if I type  s = "One two three" and then len(s) I get 13, so I am very confused.

Comment: How do you think spaces are stored in a file? Magic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"One two three" is indeed 13 chars (11 letters + 2 spaces).

```
>>> open("file.txt", 'w').write("one two three")
>>> len(open("file.txt").read())
13
```

Most likely you have an extra char for the endline, which explains the 14.

Comment: Yes, seems like Gedit was adding a space so that's where the 14 character was from. Thank you very much for helping me out.

Answer (score 2):

One two three

> one = 3 characters
>
> two = 3 characters
>
> three = 5 characters

and than you have `two spaces`. So a total of `13` characters.

when reading from file there is an extra `space` in your file so 14 characters.

In your python interpreter do this:

```
st = " "
len(st)
```

output = `1`

Answer (score 1):

I used your code and created file similar to your by content. Result of running: indeed you have extra non-printable character in your "One two three" file. It's the only explanation. Space and line break - most obvious things to look up for.